# How to check path existence in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have datetime paths as follow:

`/data/2020-04-01/data.csv`

`/data/2020-04-02/data.csv`

For some days, the file may not exist and If I call `spark.read.load()` function it fails. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

You can check like below,

```
import os.path
from os import path

if path.exists('/data/2020-04-01/data.csv'):
   spark.read.load('/data/2020-04-01/data.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

In databricks you can use dbutils:

```
dbutils.fs.ls(path)
```

Using this function, you will get all the valid paths that exist. You can also use following hadoop library to get valid paths from hdfs:

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs
```

Comment: I am using pyspark and it seems like org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(path) is for scala, can I use it in Python or any other way?

Comment: You can use it in python like this: sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(Path)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a list of data paths and want to load data for the paths which exists on HDFS. You can pass your path to the get method in FileSystem. If the path doesn't exist it will throw IOException, and then you can proceed with the next set of paths.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;   
         
// method to get files which exists
public static List<String> listFilesForBasePath(String path, Configuration conf) throws IOException {
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Path(path).toUri(), conf);
        FileStatus[] items = fs.listStatus(new Path(path));
        List<String> files = new ArrayList<>();
        for (FileStatus item : items) {
            files.add(item.getPath().toString());
        }
        return files;
}

// read files as :
Configuration configuration = sparkSession.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration(); 
List<String> inputPaths = listFilesForBasePath(basePath, configuration)
Dataset<String> dataSet = sparkSession.read().textFile(inputPaths.toArray(new String[0]));
```

Comment: it's pyspark, thus, Python and **not** Scala

Comment: @UninformedUser, we can call scala or java library functions in python using  sc._jvm in function call. For example: sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(Path).

Answer (score 0):

To fix issue in **Simple way**, Define your schema & apply that before loading. It will work without files in specified directory.

Check below code.

```
scala> import sys.process._
import sys.process._

scala> "ls -ltr D:\\tmp\\data\\customers".! // I don't have files inside directory.
total 0
```

Defining schema

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

scala> val schema = DataType.fromJson("""{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"name","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"age","type":"integer","nullable":false,"metadata":{}}]}""").asInstanceOf[StructType] // Definining schema
```

Reading files from empty directory `without schema` will `fail`.

```
scala> spark.read.load("D:\\tmp\\data\\customers") // Reading file without schema will fail.
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:185)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:185)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:184)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:373)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
  ... 61 elided
```

Reading files from empty directory with `schema`.

```
scala> spark.read.schema(schema).load("D:\\tmp\\data\\customers") // Reading files from directory with predefined schema.
res80: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, age: int]

scala> val df = spark.read.schema(schema).load("D:\\tmp\\data\\customers") // Reading files from directory with predefined schema.
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, age: int]

scala> df.count
res81: Long = 0
```

Comment: Nice, but what if I want to do inferschema? I am not having the schema, have to get it from file.

Comment: You can get the schema from one file and store that in json format ..convert json schema to schema.. whenever you need.. in the above example I did the same.

Comment: InferSchema will work only if files are available in directory.. it will try to infer schema.. if files are not available it will fail with the above error.