# Spark read empty directory

Tags: scala, apache-spark

trying to read an empty parquet directory, getting this error

> Unable to specify schema for parquet. Must be specified manually

my code

```
val myObject = spark.read.parquet(path).as[MyClass].filter(p => ......)
```

Tried handling with scala 'Try' and a regular check for empty directory

```
myObject.rdd.isEmpty
```

Any Ideas

Comment: Check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62917008/how-to-check-path-existence-in-spark/62920533?r=SearchResults#62920533

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
var myObject: DataFrame = null
try {
   myObject = spark.read.parquet(path).as[MyClass].filter(p => ......)
catch {
  case ae: AnalysisException =>
    //Do your logic here
}
```

In this scenario the "myObject.rdd.isEmpty" isn't going to work because it needs to load the directory and infer schema and after that to check if is empty.

To make it work you can do something like this:

```
val customSchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("id", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("name", StringType, true),
  StructField("email", StringType, true))
)

val myObject = spark.read.schema(customSchema).parquet(path).as[MyClass].filter(p => ......)

if(myObject.rdd.isEmpty) {
   //Do something
}
else {
  //Do something else
}
```